# django app does not activate models

Tags: python, django

In my Django app cannot activate models.

`manage.py validate` return 0 error, no matter what I do, even if I type wrong code on purpose.
`manage.py syncdb` does not sync anything.

How can I fix this?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'YolaSite.consumer',
    'south',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Here is DB connection:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'testdb',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'postgres',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': 'alexsis',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
}
```

}

Comment: what is the error returned?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? How is your database connection defined?

Comment: Give some more information, or show errors which you have got?

Comment: Django 1.4.9 python 2.7.3

Comment: there are no errors returned, that's the problem

Comment: I've been able to activate models first time, so the version of the website (django app) is actually working, but now that I try to change models it seems that it is not being recognized.

Comment: Django does not handle model changes in version 1.4. Use [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) for that.

Comment: I posted db connection above. maybe the problem is that I use postgres user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's `syncdb` command only creates tables at first time, but doesn't support model evolution.

But as we can see you have already installed South, which is the right tool for database/schema migrations. The next step is that you need to tell South which models it has to take care of.

As long as you have only a development environment I would suggest to delete all tables of your own apps and then follow the instructions in the [South tutorial](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html).

In short:

First, tell South to watch the models of a specific app and create the initial migration:

```
./manage.py schemamigration your_app_name --initial
```

Second, apply this migration to your database:

```
./manage.py migrate your_app_name
```

Third, any upcoming changes to your models need a new migration, which can be generated like this:

```
./manage.py schemamigration your_app_name --auto
```

And every migration has to be deployed, so again:

```
./manage.py migrate your_app_name
```

For more information read the [South docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> I've been able to activate models first time, so the version of the website (django app) is actually working, but now that I try to change models it seems that it is not being recognized.

You've successfully used `manage.py syncdb` to create the database table, and now you're trying to use it to "sync" changes.  That isn't what syncdb does, though.  The documentation (found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#syncdb)) for Django 1.4 reads:

> **Syncdb will not alter existing tables**
>
> syncdb will only create tables for models which have not yet been installed. It will never issue ALTER TABLE statements to match changes made to a model class after installation. Changes to model classes and database schemas often involve some form of ambiguity and, in those cases, Django would have to guess at the correct changes to make. There is a risk that critical data would be lost in the process.
>
> If you have made changes to a model and wish to alter the database tables to match, use the sql command to display the new SQL structure and compare that to your existing table schema to work out the changes.

Which is why you aren't getting any errors.  For database migration, use South, which you have installed.  Read its documentation for it's usage.

Answer (score 0):

You may use south,
or drop your table and syncdb again